# Reduce the Task Idle Conditions timeout from 15mins to 5mins

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> #### Detecting the Idle State
>
> In Windows 7, the Task Scheduler verifies that the computer is in an idle state every 15 minutes.

Is there a way to lower that to, say, 5 minutes?

Comment: have you tested what you intend to do using the idle trigger or what are you trying to do?  I do not believe in win7 it is every 15 minutes, or possibly not for what you intend to do. Idle triggers default is 3 minutes, and people have reported it working in 3 minutes after idle. (although idle triggers can have programs that intentionally block idle, and other unexpected things.)  On the other hand people have asked more than once why a scheduled task did not start at the scheduled time, but Not when using idle triggers.

Comment: @Psycogeek Thanks for the info, interesting. I'm testing it now but it doesn't seem to be 3 minutes. Infact it's pretty arbitrary. Sometimes it triggers in 1 minute, sometimes it takes even longer than 15 (mostly it's >15 though). Which makes me think that 15 minutes cycle is independent of when the PC begins to be idle. I need to test some more though before being sure.

Comment: That alone sounds like it does indeed have some sort of 15 minute cycle, now if there just happen to be a registry setting that adjusted it.

Comment: there are config items here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Configuration  nothing obvious to me, and a web search using that didnt show any tweak additions.  There is always running as a screen saver, I think there was even code wrapping for creating a screen saver from an exe, to make running a program as a SS easy.